# Building ASP.NET with MVC, trying to create a filter from Dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First post here so be gentle please :)

I am creating an ASP.NET with MVC web app that shows a list of items of the same class (Laptop)
I want to create a Dropdown list in the main view below each title that will allow me to filter the results OnChange - hence the selection is empty, but the user can click and select the value in the DropDown list, and the main view items list will update immediately according to the selection.

This is how the list looks now:
[Snapshot of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHNBR.png)

I want to implement a dropdown, but I can't seem to get the selected value from the dropdown: (The DropDownlist is populated properly, and working)

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<purpose>()"
        onchange="@{Model = Model.Where(m=>m.Purpose == /*HERE SHOULD BE THE VALUE SELECTED*/)}">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-Select one-</option>
</select>
```

And then refreshing the page... but - how do I get the selected value from inside the selection?

If it was in JavaScript I would have done:

```
html.document.getElementById("The id of the selection").value
```

but I don't want JavaScript since this is all ASP.NET

To be clear, I have 5 different dropdown lists to filter by, and they can be selected or not.

Comment: do you wanted to implement cascade dropdown in your application ? Correct me if i understood something worng. if i am on same pich you should try thi https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/ Let me know if you facing any other issue there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am not trying to create the dropdown - that's done.
I'm trying to get the value selected from the dropdown.
Can I do this without ajax?

EDIT: it is possible the link you sent will solve this. i'll try and let you know.
Thanks!

Comment: `onchange="@{Model = Model.Where(m=>m.Purpose == /*HERE SHOULD BE THE VALUE SELECTED*/)}">` ...it's unclear what you think you're trying to do here. `onchange` is a client-side event. So you're supposed to put a call to a javascript function in there, e.g. `onchange="someFunction()"`. Then in `someFunction()` you can use Javascript to get the currently selected value in the dropdown.But if you want to then use that information on the server-side, you need to either send the value via AJAX, or forget the javascript and just wait for the form to be submitted, and the server would receive it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up client-side vs. server-side code. The example below uses only MVC and a full client-server architecture. Each request requires a round-trip to the server.

You have 3 components in this scenario.

ProductsViewModel.cs

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public IList<Laptop> Laptops { get; set; }

    public PurposeEnum Purpose { get; set; }
}
```

ProductsController.cs

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Retrieve all records without a filter
        var unfiltered = db.Laptops.ToList();
        var viewModel = new ProductsViewModel() { AvailableLaptops = unfiltered };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(ProductsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Use viewModel.Purpose & viewModel.Maker to filter records from database
        var filtered = db.Laptops.Where(l => l.Purpose == viewModel.Purpose).ToList();

        var filteredViewModel = new ProductsViewModel()
        {
            AvailableLaptops = filtered,
            Purpose = viewModel.Purpose
        };

        return filteredViewModel;
    }
}
```

Products\Index.cshtml

```
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModel

using (BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList(Html.GetEnumSelectList<PurposeEnum>())

    foreach (var l in Model.AvailableLaptops)
    {
        // Loop through Model.AvailableLaptops and generate table
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

When you visit the URL /Products/Index for the first time, the GET action handler will be triggered. It will generate an unfiltered list of your products along with the dropdown list required for filtering.

When you make your selection and submit the form, the POST action handler will be triggered, and use the selected values in the Purpose and Maker properties of the view model to filter the records. The same view is generated, but with a filtered down list of products.

This is very basic code that ignores validation, error handling and security.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I do confuse both, but I am a student, so...
This does solve my question. I was trying to avoid having many possibilities.
I have more than one filter, so writing a complex switch (binary-like) seemed like too much code for the capabilities of ASP but I see I should go the simple approach :)
Thank you again, it clarifies everything I need.